# how to redirect from one controller to another with object and send response back to original view in mvc4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a view `login.cshtml` in my web_application and two controller `Controller_1` and `Controller_2`. Request generated form view contains some object of `Person` class. Initially request is passed to some method `User_Login` of Controller_1. now i want to redirect the request from Controller_1 to some method method `new_method` in Controller_2 with the Person object and it should send response back to login.chtml page. please suggest me something...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RedirectToAction` method in `User_Login` of `Controller1` and redirect to action in `Controller2`. In your action in `Controller2` you can specify the desired view.

Lets say the instance of Person you get in action of `Controller1` is `person`.

```
RedirectToAction("ActioninController2","Controller2", person);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @user3083131 no worries!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RedirectToAction("ActionName","ControllerName")`. Person Object you can pass in `TempData["someName"] = YourPersonObject` and in your second controller/action get:

```
var person = TempData["someName"];
```

Last job to do is generate View for example:

```
return View("pathToView");
```

or PartialView

```
return PartialView("PathToView");
```